# Read data in a HTML data

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have downloaded the HTML data from a website using webclient class. Now I want to read the data in between tags. I came to know about htmlagilitypack, but I don't want to use it. 
I am using the following code to get the HTML data.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string url = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
        Byte[] requestedHTML; 
        requestedHTML = client.DownloadData(url);
        string htmlcode = client.DownloadString(url);

        //client.DownloadFile(url, @"E:\test.html");

        UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string html = objUTF8.GetString(requestedHTML);
        Response.Write(html);
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use HTMLAgilityPack?

Comment: @Muad'Dib got a good point 46 questions asked and only 1 third accepted is a bit low...

Comment: Ok I will do that whenever i get a free time.. Now can anybody give answer to this question?

Comment: Which Data you want to read, means value of any specific tag/Element ?

Comment: The Html data contains table tag in it. In that many <tr> existed. one of the <tr> contains data which I want to retrieve. This is the thing I want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string url = "Your URL";
        Byte[] requestedHTML;
        requestedHTML = client.DownloadData(url);
        string htmlcode = client.DownloadString(url);

        //client.DownloadFile(url, @"E:\test.html");

        UTF8Encoding objUTF8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        string html = objUTF8.GetString(requestedHTML);           


        MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"(<h3>(.*?)</h3>)",
        RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match m in m1)
        {
            string cell = m.Groups[1].Value;
            Match match = Regex.Match(cell, @"<h3>(.+?)</h3>");
            if (match.Success)
            {
                string value = match.Groups[1].Value;
            }
        }
```

The string value will give you the value = "Chicago"

Comment: The Html data contains table tag in it. In that many <tr> existed. one of the <tr> contains data which I want to retrieve. This is the thing I want to know.

Comment: Can you give the URL from which you want to read the data and which specific data you want to read from a row??

Comment: URL : http://zipinfo.com/cgi-local/zipsrch.exe?zip=60680.. Here I am passing Zip code to the site and getting the related data. The HTML data contains the City name of the given Zipcode, here city name I got is Chicago(You can see it in the html data). this is the value I want to retrieve.

Comment: Yey, The Tez is right, regex is quite fast..I modified the answer try out that

Comment: @ BreakHead: Just 2 minutes before it was working but now it is not. MatchCollection count is 0. I am not understanding why it happenned like this

Comment: I found the issue. The URL which I gave will work for only 30 trials. I crossed the limit.

Comment: either keep this string htmlcode = client.DownloadString(url); or requestedHTML = client.DownloadData(url); it creating unwanted calls

Comment: Now I am not using the url which I gave you. I want to use http://www.findlocalweather.com/forecast.php?config=&forecast=zandh&pands=60680.  Can you give me the regex code to get the city name from this URL?

Answer (score 3):

Use Regular Expressions instead.